# RegEx to filter E-Mail Adresses from URLs in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I want to use a Google Analytics filter to remove email addresses from incoming URIs. I am using the custom advanced filter, filtering field A on a RegEx for the Request URI and replacing the respective part later. However, my RegEx does not seem to work correctly. It should find email addresses, not only if an '@' is used, but also if '(at)', '%40', or '$0040' are used to represent the '@'.

My latest RegEx version (see below) still allows '$0040' to go through undetected. Can someone advise me what to change?

```
^(.*)=([A-Z0-9._%+-]+[@|[\(at\)]|[\$0040]|[\%40]][A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})(.*)$
```

Comment: Try [`=([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+(@|\(at\)|[$]0040|\%40)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})`](https://regex101.com/r/Ica4jZ/2). If you need to match the whole string, you may keep that pattern enclosed with your `^(.*)` and`(.*)$`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My first test's show that it should do the trick, but GA has always it's special ways to tweak that stuff, so I will review the collected data tomorrow again. ; )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```
([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+(@|\(at\)|[$]0040|\%40)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A‌​-Za-z]{2,4})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ica4jZ/3).

If you need to match the whole string, you may keep that pattern enclosed with your `^(.*)` and `(.*)$`.

**Details**

- `([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+(@|\(at\)|[$]0040|\%40)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A‌​-Za-z]{2,4})` - Group 1 capturing

  - `[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+` -  1 or more ASCII letters/digits, `.`, `_`, `%`, `+`, or `-`
  - `(@|\(at\)|[$]0040|\%40)` - one of the alternatives: `@`, `(at)`, `$0040` or `%40`
  - `[A-Za-z0-9.-]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters/digits, `.` or `-`
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `[A‌​-Za-z]{2,4}` - 2 to 4 ASCII letters.

Comment: Thanks. That did the job. For my aim, I actually had to remove the '='. I guess that the previous aim of the regex I had was to screen UTM codes only, and not whole URLs.